# set nested html element visible

Tags: html, css

```
<p style="display:inline" id="tags">
  <span><i class="fas fa-tag"></i></span>
<p style="display:inline" contenteditable="true">`+elem.tags.join(',')+`</p>
<span style="display:inline" id ="icon_span_id" class="glyphicon">&#x270f;</span>
   <br><br>
                    </p>
```

I'm trying to set icon_span_id to be visible on hover. This is my code thus far; but doesn't do the magic.

```
.animated_blinker {
  animation: blinker 2s linear infinite;
}
#tags #icon_span_id{
  visibility: hidden;
}
#tags:hover #icon_span_id{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: that's not how it works, your css currently is incorrect. you probably need javascript for this, are you okay using that?

Comment: I'm okay using js for it. Can you tell me how I'd be able to use it.

Comment: never mind, I actually didn't know it existed like this. The below answer is correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Right now your inline style is just taking precedence over the `hover` style.  Move the `visibility: hidden` style out from in-line and into its own style and it will work.

https://jsfiddle.net/4wt6f1y3/10/

```
<p id="tags">
   <span><i class="fas fa-tag"></i></span>Some text
   <span id ="icon_span_id" class="glyphicon">&#x270f;</span>
                      <br><br>
</p>

#tags #icon_span_id{
  visibility: hidden;
  color:red;
}
#tags:hover #icon_span_id{
  visibility: visible;
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Hey, when I add <p> tag within it; it stopped working. Why's that? @Steve

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

add jquery to catch event on hover and mouse leave : 
this a bit of jquery :

```
$('#tags').mouseenter(function() {
$('#icon_span_id').removeAttr('style');}).mouseleave(function() {      
$('#icon_span_id').attr('style', 'visibility:hidden');});
```

check code preview here : 
https://codepen.io/navotera/pen/YvqGgE